# Как изменить символы в шаблоне, заменив {{ и }} на <% и %> ? -Golang

Tags: golang, шаблоны

Есть хандлер

```
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {    
    var templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("Templates/Main/*/*"))
    var doc bytes.Buffer 
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(&doc, "indexPage", nil)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    } 
    //templates.Delims("<%", "%>").Funcs(Main_TemplateFuncs).Parse("<%шаблон   %>")    
    fmt.Fprintln(w, &doc)
}
```

Мне нужно переназначить символы {{ и }} , так как я использую в angularjs такие же символы.
Есть функция templates.Delims("<%", "%>"), которая переназначет их, но она работает, если после неё в Parse закинешь текст.
А у меня идёт множество файлов  template.Must(template.ParseGlob("Templates/Main/*/*")) и как мне их обработать, заменив стандартную обработку {{ и }}  на <% и %> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
templ := template.New("templ")
//поменять символы
templ.Delims("<%", "%>")
//и парсить туда
var templates = template.Must(templ.ParseGlob("Templates/Main/*/*"))
```